# How can i validate textbox on keypress to allow only alphanumeric characters in blazor server

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

```
<InputText @onkeypress="inputfname" id="name" @bind-Value="@model.FirstName">

@code{
    private string _filterRegexPattern = "^[a - zA - Z] *$";

    protected void inputfname(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {

        if(model.FirstName != _filterReqexPattern)
        {
            fname = "only characters required";
        }
        else
        {
            fname = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *block* the user input I would probably just handle this with an `oninput` regex. It's going to handle some additional edge cases, like pasting.

```
<InputText oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');" id="name" @bind-Value="@model.FirstName" />
```

For server side validation you can use the [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0) on the `model.FirstName` property.

Answer (score -1):

Found this https://www.meziantou.net/validating-an-input-on-keypress-instead-of-on-change-in-blazor.htm
Did not test but looks like it is doing what you are asking.